# Why is this method giving two different results?

Tags: c++, qt

So I have a class called `HugeInt` which stores a dynamic array of integers with each place corresponding to a decimal place (arr[0] = 2^0, arr[1] = 2^1...). So I also have this method `reverse`, which reverses the numbers. But in main it gives two different results, can anyone help? `DynArray` is the dynamic array class I have created. It just contains an array of int which resizes based on if we are adding to the array. (Cannot use vectors)

```
HugeInt HugeInt::reverse(){
    HugeInt hi;
    for (int i = 0; i < this->size; i++){
        hi.dyn.add(this->dyn[this->size - 1 - i]);
    }
    return hi;
}
```

My print functions:

```
void HugeInt::print(){
    dyn.print();
}

void DynArray::print(){
    for (int i = 0; i < nextIndex; i++){
        std::cout << arr[i];
    }
}
```

my operator=:

```
HugeInt& HugeInt::operator=(const HugeInt &b1)
{
    this->dyn = b1.dyn;
    this->size = b1.size;
    return *this;
}
```

When I run this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    HugeInt hi4("123456");

    hi4.print();
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    hi4.reverse().print();
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    hugeInt = hi4.reverse();
    hugeInt.print();
}
```

I get these results:

```
123456

654321

3854321
```

Why is the last result different from the second result? I am not used to coding in c++ so I feel like it might be some kind of c++ thing I am overlooking?

UPDATE: 
ok so I am totally lost now. I changed my reverse() to :

```
HugeInt HugeInt::reverse()
{
    return *this;
}
```

and my main as:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    HugeInt hi4("123456");

    hi4.reverse().print();
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    hugeInt = hi4.reverse();
    hugeInt.print();
}
```

and get the results

```
123456

3223456
```

32 on the ASCII table is 'Space' and 38 is & which is what it was saying before. I'm so lost!

Comment: What happens when you remove `this->~HugeInt();`? (BTW you should almost never call the destructor manually)

Comment: Issues with copy constructors et al? I see none

Comment: As @JesseGood said, why are you destroying it?

Comment: what is that for: `this->~HugeInt();` ?

Comment: ok i removed the manual call to the destructor but it still its not exactly the same.

Comment: @JanDvorak It is probably the copy copy constructor? Since I have none

Comment: try step by step debugging.

Comment: @gongzhitaao I am having issues debugging in QT at the moment :/

Comment: what is `nextIndex` in `DynArray` and what are you doing with it?

Comment: @FKaria nextIndex is the next empty spot in the array. Basically the size of the hugeInt

Comment: have you defined '=' operator? If you reveive consistenly stable results with hi4.reverse().print(); and different every time with hugeInt = hi4.reverse();
Then you really should implement "=" operator

Comment: @user2230341 You can probably see that people are having trouble guessing details about your program that you haven't shown.  Please take the time to make a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) so we are all looking at the same code.

Comment: Have you implement copy constructor for your DYN class?

Answer (score 3):

This line in `HugeInt HugeInt::reverse()` is **bad**.

```
this->~HugeInt();
```

That means that the first time you call `hi4.reverse()`, you destroy `hi4`.

Every time it's used afterwards is undefined behavior.

**Remove that line.**  I can't figure out what you were hoping to do there, but "nothing" is probably a better thing to do there.

Comment: Gotcha. I shall remember that for future reference, I am still new to c++

Answer (score 0):

I tried to implement your problem. I had to improvise little bit on those class insides, but this code works flawlessly with `MS VS 2010`.

My program:

```
//file: header.h
//author: kupto
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>

class DynArray
{
    std::vector<char> arr;

public:
    void print();
    void add(char c) {arr.push_back(c);};
    char get(int pos) {return (arr[pos]);};
    int size() {return arr.size();};
};

void DynArray::print()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < this->size(); i++)
        std::cout << arr[i];
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

class HugeInt
{
    DynArray dyn;

public:
    void print() {dyn.print();}
    int size() {return (dyn.size());}

    HugeInt HugeInt::reverse();

    HugeInt(char* str);
    HugeInt() {};

};

HugeInt::HugeInt(char* str)
{
    char c;
    int i = 0;
    c = str[i];

    while (c)
    {
        dyn.add(c);
        c = str[++i];
    }
}

HugeInt HugeInt::reverse()
{
    HugeInt hi;
    for (int i = 0; i < this->size(); i++){
        hi.dyn.add(this->dyn.get(this->size() - 1 - i));
    }
    return hi;
}
```

and the source file:

```
//file: source.cpp
//author: Kupto
#include "header.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    HugeInt hi4("123456");

    hi4.print();
    hi4.reverse().print();
    HugeInt hugeInt = hi4.reverse();
    hugeInt.print();
    hi4 = hugeInt;
    hi4.print();
    hi4 = hi4.reverse();
    hi4.print();
    return 0x00;
}
```

The output is as expected:

```
123456
654321
654321
654321
123456
```

Note, that I used `DynArray::get(int)` method instead your `operator[int]`.
Good luck with your code.

Comment: Hmm I am using QT Creator, I feel like it should work but maybe it has to do with the IDE i'm using?

Comment: Might be as well... I have no experience with QT Creator. You might consider posting your trimmed code (trim it as long as you can produce this error) perhaps we could have a look at it.